# Is revolution possible anymore?

Tags: civil-war

When a government ceases to serve its citizens or becomes hostile to them, it is the right of the people to rise up and replace it. This has happened many times in history.

But several lifestyle changes in our recent past make me wonder if this can ever happen again.

Society is becoming increasingly comfortable and urbanized. Many people are unaccustomed to manual labor, let alone combat. This comfort also affects mental fortitude; it may make people more willing to tolerate a dictatorship than face the horrors of war.

Whereas a revolutionary army and a state army were once two groups of men with swords, governments now have far more powerful matériel. Furthermore, they are gradually disarming their citizens entirely by tightening laws around weapons. I think this is a laudable goal with the public safety of the current state in mind, but with the cycles of history in mind it is an alarming change.

Are the states we live in now eternal?

Comment: "Furthermore, they are gradually disarming their citizens entirely by tightening laws around weapons."  This is incorrect.  Gun ownership in the U.S. is continually increasing over time.  I would focus more on the fact that the U.S. military has significantly more advanced, expensive, heavy duty weaponry than citizens can practically own (military-owned tanks and jets drastically outnumber civilian-owned tanks and jets).  The military budget is a multiple the size of China's and Russia's military budgets.  The extraordinary size of the military matters more than the gun laws.

Comment: @John True, but the US is not the only state.

Comment: @Joe You're right.  On first reading, I inferred that this had a particularly American focus (maybe because the U.S.'s military / police strength is so relevant to the theme of the question).  Plus, some Americans believe in the myth of citizen disarmament, so again, I inferred an American focus.  But realistically, the gun control aspect of the question definitely makes more sense in the context of other West European / East Asian / Australasian countries.

Comment: You don't need a heavily armed populace to have a revolution - you just need enough guns to take control of an armory.

Comment: If you're talking about revolutions in general, then a quick look at the [list of revolutions over just the last decade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revolutions_and_rebellions#2010s) will show that revolutions are certainly possible. If you're talking about just a specific country, then you should say which country and also note that you can easily have a revolt without weapons.

Answer (score 6):

## No. Revolution is still possible.

While there are factors which make revolutions more difficult, there are other factors which make them easier.

- Revolutions happen when the population no longer believes in the legitimacy of the government. This affects the military and police as well. If there is widespread popular discontent, **the military becomes unreliable**.
- The internet can be used to spread discontent and mobilize populations. It is increasingly integrated into the economy. A government would find it difficult to shut it down for any length of time. As China has shown, controlling the internet is **possible but difficult**. Only stable governments can afford that.
- Most military forces are much smaller as a percentage of the population than they used to be. They would have trouble enforcing martial law over the **entire** country.

Regarding gun laws, there is great variation and there are quite a lot of myths. According to [not quite recent estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimated_number_of_civilian_guns_per_capita_by_country), France, Germany and Iraq have the same number of civilian firearms per capita. And that number is higher than that of Libya which did have a revolution ...